# Reuse subquery for filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a function `set_size()` which takes a jsonb and returns the size of the object. Say also, that I can guaranteed that any json object is only ever contained exactly in one other json object, and I have a function `is_superset(jsonb, jsonb)` which returns true if the former is the parent of the latter and false otherwise.

Say I now have something like so:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN size = 0
  THEN SELECT (set_size(container.set)) size
  FROM my_table container
  WHERE is_superset(container.set, initial.set)
  ELSE size
FROM (SELECT set_size(initial.set) size FROM my_table) initial
WHERE initial.id != container.id
```

This results in `missing FROM-clause entry for table "container"`

How can I reuse subquery results like this? What would be a reasonable way to achieve this result? (e.g. filter out the original selection)

EDIT: the table structure:

```
 set                  | id
------------------------------------------
 {}                   | 1                  --size 0
 {a: {}}              | 2                  --size 1, 'contains' first set
 {b: {c: {a: 5}}      | 3                  --size 3
```

expected result:

```
id           | size
------------------------
1            | 2
3            | 3
```

Please note, I am aware that this doesn't make a huge amount of sense as a jsonb query, and *am not* looking for help finding the right jsonb operations. The real problem deals with postgis, geometries, and `ST_Area`/`ST_Contains`. But this question demonstrates the relational problem I am having in a more general way.

Comment: `size` is `my_table ` column?.. please put some sample data and some expected result

Comment: edited to provide a mock schema / results